# making d3.js compatible with ie

Tags: d3.js, internet-explorer-8, javascript

Please help me in making d3.js compatible with ie8/ie9. It is working fine in firefox and chrome. It gives me the following error in IE8:

Object doesn't support this property or method in d3.v3.min.js at this line:

Qa=["y","z","a","f","p","n","Âµ","m","","k","M","G","T","P","E","Z","Y"].map(yt);

Comment: d3 doesn't support IE8 out of the box: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#browser-support

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159002/d3-js-browser-support

Comment: Hi Adam, I am using the latest version of d3.v3.js, I making a zoomable tree map using d3. It works well in Chrome and Firefox but not in iE9. It gives me the following error                               SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'setProperty': object is null or undefined 
d3.v3.js, line 659 character 60                                             Can you please help me with this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are utf-8 characters in the d3.js file.

See this issue:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195

Fixes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or

`<script charset="utf-8" src="d3.js"></script>`

Comment: The issue link is giving a 404 not found. Could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with map and forEach functions support. You need to use [r2d3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3) and [aight](https://github.com/shawnbot/aight) instead of d3.js.