# How to make a D3 works in IE5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My Application Works in IE5, In Application i am using D3.js..its working in IE9 and above versions by adding meta tag with content="IE=edge"...I need it work in IE5 also..
Can anyOne help me out from this..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159002/d3-js-browser-support

Comment: What on earth could be the reason for you to support IE 5 ?

Comment: D3 does not officially support IE5.