# Updating WebView on Android 5

Tags: javascript, android, d3.js, svg, webview

I am trying to create a WebView application for Moverio BT-300 (Android 5.1). I've got it to run some javascript files, but I couldn't get d3.js (Version 4.11) to work properly on the BT-300.

The d3 script runs perfectly on the exact same WebView application on Acer tablet, so I suspect it is the problem of the WebView version. With `Log.i("WebViewActivity", "UA: " + webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString());` this is the output on the Acer tablet:

```
I/WebViewActivity: UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; A3-A30 Build/LRX22G; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/61.0.3163.98 Safari/537.36
```

and on the Moverio BT-300:

```
I/WebViewActivity: UA: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; EMBT3C Build/R1.4.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/39.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Even though the Android is newer, the Moverio has a much older Chrome, and my question here is how do I update this to a newer version?

-- My attempts --

- I downloaded the WebView APK [here](http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/android-system-webview-apk-latest-download/) and installed on the Moverio, but the WebView is still using the older version of Chrome.
- Android 7 has an option called **change WebView implementation**, but this is not an option for Android 5.

-- Side note --

The fact that d3 doesn't work can mean one of the libraries it uses aren't compatible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582016/4204593). However, the Moverio WebView can run CSS script, manipulate DOM with js, plays HTML5 video, and draws SVG. Library compatibility can the issue, but updating WebView is a more straightforward approach so I won't have to water down future development in d3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is found. I used padStart() in my js, and chrome does not support it until 57. There is nothing wrong with D3 compatibility, it works after I remove padStart()!